# Servlet not working with Tomcat 6.0.37

Tags: java, servlets

I have a development folder having following structure:

```
G:\MyProjects\beerV1--
                      |___classes\com\examples\web\BeerSelect.class
                      |_______src\com\examples\web\BeerSelect.java
                      |_____etc\web.xml
                      |_____web\form.html
```

My deployment folder hierarchy is:

```
C:\Tomcat6\apache-tomcat-6.0.37\webapps\Beer-v1
                                        ---WEB-INF\classes\com\examples\web\BeerSelect.class
                                        ---form.html
                                        ---WEB-INF\web.xml
```

When I run the `http://localhost:8080/` , I can see the default tomcat page.
However I'm not able to see the form page using `http://localhost:8080/Beer-v1/form.html`( getting `404 error`)

Am I missing something here?

The `BeerSelect.java` is:

```
package com.examples.web;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class BeerSelect extends HttpServlet {

    public void doHost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        out.println("Beer Selection Advice<br>");
        String c=request.getParameter("color");
        out.println("<br>Got beer color "+c);
    }
}
```

My `web.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee web-app_2_4.xsd"
         Version="2.4">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Ch3Beer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.examples.web.BeerSelect</servlet-class>
</servlet>    

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Ch3Beer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>/SelectBeer.do</servlet-class>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and my `form.html` is:

```
<html>
    <!--Some sample HTML-->
    <head>
        <title>The english pub</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align="center">Beer Selection Page</h1>

        <form method="POST"action="SelectBeer.do">
            Select beer characteristics<p>
                Color:
                <select name="color" size="1">
                    <option value="light"> light </option>
                    <option value="amber"> amber </option>
                    <option value="brown"> brown </option>
                </select>
                <br><br>

            <center><input type="SUBMIT"</center>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do we have a method named doHost() in HttpServlet? I think your `doHost()` should be changed to `doPost()` as your action in html says to POST the request.

HTML:

```
<form method="POST"action="SelectBeer.do">
```

Servlet:

```
public class BeerSelect extends HttpServlet {

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        out.println("Beer Selection Advice<br>");
        String c=request.getParameter("color");
        out.println("<br>Got beer color "+c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi svjn Sorry for the typo and thx for your reply.I corrected and recompiled and replaced that .class file everywhere still facing the issue.

Comment: Add `@Override` over the method to catch those kind of typos. It's pretty much the purpose of the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Found something more:

in web.xml:

```
<servlet-class>/SelectBeer.do</servlet-class>
```

should be changed to :

```
<url-pattern>/SelectBeer.do</url-pattern>
```

And this resolved the problem.

Silly mistake.

Anyways thanks for looking into the issue for me.

Cheers!